# Draw a Number Line Diagram Using Jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I can draw a number line diagram using Jquery and CSS.  Please take a look at my code snippet below.

Every 10% of the width, I have a tiny line and it repeats until the end of the line.  Now, at 5th tiny line for example, I need to replace it with a dot and dots will keep on showing after every 10th, 15th, 20th... to the end of the line. But I don't know how get it.  Please give a hand.  THANKS!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  for(var i = 0; i< 40; i++)
    $(".BG").append('<div class="scale"></div>'); 

     
});
```

```css
.BG {
  display: flex;
  border-top: 5px solid gray;
  position: relative;
}
.scale {
  width: 10%;
 /*  border-top: 5px solid green; */
}
.scale:after {
  content: "";
  width: 1px;
  height: 7px;
  background-color: black;
  float: right;
  /* margin-top: -4px; */
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="BG">

</div>
```

Comment: every 10% will give you 10 lines not 40

Answer (score 0):

JS

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      for(var i = 1; i<= 40; i++) {
        if (i%5 === 0) {
          $(".BG").append('<div class="scale scaled-dot"></div>'); 
        } else {
          $(".BG").append('<div class="scale"></div>'); 
        }
      }
    });
```

CSS

```
.scaled-dot:after {
  // Modify styles with how you want the dot to look like
}
```

Comment: Hi Yalung, Thank you very much for help!  What is `if (i%5 = 0)` ?  I replaced your code, but somehow it doesn't work!  Please take a look, again.

Comment: Oops! Had an error in the code, I mistakenly added "=" instead of "===", try also creating the dot style and add it to "scaled-dot:after". The intention of it is to say that the residue of dividing "i" into 5 is equal to zero. The "for" was changed too.

Comment: Thanks, it works now, but can you control where is the first dot?  For example, the first dot should show at the 5th tiny line and the second dot will be 10th, and so on.

Comment: Yes, just add a case for it on the if, like this :D -> if (i%5 === 0 || i === 1)

Answer (score 0):

A pure CSS solution can do this.

Example where I used random value that you can easily adjust

```css
.BG {
  height:20px;
  background:
    radial-gradient(circle closest-side,red 97%,transparent 100%) 
      44% 0 /  /* adjust the 44% to control the position */
      calc(100%/5) 100%, /* adjust the 5 to control the space between circle */
     
    repeating-linear-gradient(to right, 
        black     0 2px, /* change the 2px to adjust the width of the bars */
        transparent 2px calc(100%/20)), /* adjust the 20 to control the number of bars */
    
    linear-gradient(gray,gray) center/100% 10px no-repeat;
  border-right:2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="BG">

</div>
```

Comment: The dot is not being added at the specified nth ocurrence

Comment: @YalungTang I said *I used random value that you can easily adjust*